# How to count the number of rows containing a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-datatables

I'm using AngularJS and I have a table that I populate using `ng-repeat`. Check this short example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sso3ktz4/

How do I check how many rows I have with a certain value? For example, in the fiddle above, how do I check how many rows I have with the word "second"? It should return "3".

AngularJS answers are preferred, although I also have JQuery available.

Thanks!

Comment: Please always include your code in the question

Comment: using jQuery `$('table td:contains(second)').length`

Comment: Did you tried my code for Angular?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I apologize for the lack of code but I didn't have any code worth posting. All I had were failed attempts that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated controller code is below, where $scope.findRowCount is required function

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        name: 'first',
        examples: [{
            name: 'first 1'
        }, {
            name: 'first 2'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'second',
        examples: [{
            name: 'second'
        }, {
            name: 'second'
        }]
    }];


    $scope.findRowCount=function(value){

    var count=0;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item, i){
    if(item.name==value){

      count=count+1;


    }
    angular.forEach(item.examples, function(exp, j){

    if(exp.name==value){

      count=count+1;


    }

    })




    });
    console.log("count"+count);
    return count;
    }

    var result=$scope.findRowCount("second");
    console.log(result);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p3g9vyud/

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        name: 'first',
        examples: [{
            name: 'first 1'
        }, {
            name: 'first 2'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'second',
        examples: [{
            name: 'second'
        }, {
            name: 'second'
        }]
    }];
  //Get sum based on the label
  $scope.getTotalByLabel = function(keyword)
  {
    $scope.totalSecond = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(value, key) {
        if(value.name == keyword)
        {
          $scope.totalSecond += 1;
        }
        angular.forEach(value.examples, function(val, k) {
          if(val.name == keyword)
          {
            $scope.totalSecond += 1;
          }
        });
    });
    return $scope.totalSecond;
  }
}
```

```css
th,
td {
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody ng:repeat="i in items">
            <tr>
                <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                <td>{{$index}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng:repeat="e in i.examples">
                <td>{{e.name}}</td>
                <td>{{$index}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <b>Total of second</b>: {{getTotalByLabel('second')}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That almost does what I wanted but I don't want the result to be in the HTML, but in the JavaScript. @Jekin Kalariya's answer does precisely what I want. But I thank you for your effort in trying to help me.

Comment: @T.Ferreira your welcome, my code is also having result in java-script in form of this variable. $scope.totalSecond